# Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb C$. Show $f$ is continuous on $X\iff f^{-1}(V)$ is open when $V \subseteq \mathbb C$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb C$. Prove $f$ is continuous on X $\iff f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ when $V \subseteq \mathbb C$ is open in $\mathbb C$.

I have already proved $\Rightarrow$, but I'm having trouble proving $\Leftarrow$.

Could someone help me out ?

$f$ is continuous on $X$ means: for every $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in X, d(x,x_0) \le \delta \Rightarrow \mid f(x) - f(x_0) \mid \le \epsilon$.

Comment: What is a local, pointwise definition of "open"? What is a definition of continuity at given point? It all fits together nicely ;)
Hint: consider an $\epsilon$-ball around $y=f(x)$

Comment: But continuity must apply for $X$ not just a subset.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is a metric space. How did you define continuity of maps between metric spaces?

Comment: "Continuous on $X$" means "continuous at every point of $X$". If you can show continuity for every point, that's it.

Comment: I updated with definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that for all $V$ open, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

You want to show that $f$ is continuous at any $x_0 \in X$, that is for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $d(x,x_0) \le \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \le \epsilon$.

Choose $x_0 \in X$ and $\epsilon>0$.
Then $V=B(f(x_0),\epsilon)$ is open, and hence so is $U = f^{-1} (V)$. Furthermore, we must have $x_0 \in U$, and since $U$ is open, we have some $\delta'>0$ such that $B(x_0,\delta') \subset U$.

Let $\delta = { \delta' \over 2}$, then if $d(x,x_0) \le \delta$ ($< \delta'$), we have $x \in U$ and so $f(x) \in V$, that is, $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Would you mind give some more details ?

Comment: I have added more details. If you have more questions let me know what specifically is not clear.

Comment: Aha, I missed the point we could conclude $U$ to be open (this is our assumption). Thanks for your help.